# In django, pagination is not working for second page and thereafter ,the objects are not displayed

Tags: django, pagination

when i click on "next" the objects that should be displayed on the next page is not being displayed.

but the objects are being displayed for the first page.(ie, the correct number of objects as well)

Also what is 'page' in 5th line in views.py?

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    context ={}
    search_list = Search.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(search_list, 4) # Show 4 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    search = paginator.get_page(page)
    context['search'] = search
return render(request, "main.html", context)
```

**main.html (template)**

```
    {% for result in search %}
      <br>
      {{ forloop.counter }}
      <br>
      {{ result.Query }}
      <!-- {{ search.Result.name }} -->
      <br>
      {{ result.json }}
      <br>
      <br>
      {{ result.json.name }}
      <br>
      <br>
      {{ result.json.price }}
      <br>
      <br>
      {{ result.json.author }}
      <br>
   {% endfor %}

            <div class="pagination">
                <span class="step-links">
                    {% if search.has_previous %}
                        <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
                        <a href="?page={{ search.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                    {% endif %}

                    <span class="current">
                        {{ posts.paginator.count }}
                        Page {{ search.number }} of {{ search.paginator.num_pages }}.
                    </span>

                    {% if search.has_next %}
                        <a href="?page={{ search.next_page_number }">next</a>
                        <a href="?page={{ search.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of: `page = request.GET.get('page', 1)` you need to do just `page = request.GET.get('page')`
The `get_page()` method on the next line takes care of displaying first page if `request.GET['page']` doesn't exists or contains non-integer value.

Look at your template:

```
<a href="?page={{ search.next_page_number }">next</a> // missing  closing bracket
<a href="?page={{ search.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

Comment: No Vaibhav, it didn't work when i removed the 1 as well. Still it's not showing objects in second page, Thank you for trying

Comment: also "page" variable value is returning None on printing it in console, shouldn't it return a number?

Comment: i didn't understand what you meant by GET parameter in the template. It's always returning None

Comment: That's not how it is displayed. that's not the url that is showing up , the url showing up is with csrf token

Comment: **localhost:8000/success/search/search/search/?page={{%20search.next_page_number%20}#search**  is the url being displayed

Comment: **http://localhost:8000/success/search/?page=2#search** is the url being displayed now but still no results in page 2. Thank you Vaibhav

Comment: in you question there is wrong indent in return statement of your view function. Make sure you don't have that in your actual code too.